# Обсуждение примера PHP-кода из книги

Tags: php

Я только учу PHP и читая книгу не могу понять, что автор имел ввиду.

```
interface PersonWriter
{
 public function write(Person $person)
}

class Person
{
 public function output(PersonWriter $writer)
{
 $writer->write($this);
}

public function getName()
{
 return 'Иван';
}
}
```

Автор пишет:
"В данном примере методу output() передается экземпляр объекта типа PersonWriter, методу write() которого передается экземпляр текущего класса. Благодаря такому решению класс Person аккуратно отделяется от реализации средства вывода на экран, которое переносится в клиентский код."

Можете как-то проще объяснить, что автор имел ввиду?

Что меня смущает, так то, что метод write мы же все равно должны реализовать, а не клиентский код?
Я правильно понимаю, что должен быть, например, класс, который реализует интерфес PersonWriter в котором будет логика метода write?

Например,

```
class PersonWriter implements PersonWriter
{
 function write(Person $person)
{
echo $person->getName();
}
}
```

То есть, этот код все равно нужен?

Comment: А что за книга? Может там как-то это потом всё убирается? Потому что логически для вывода нужен `PersonWriter` а вот метода `output` в `Person`  быть не должно.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, книга PHP. Объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования. Мэт Зандстра. Глава про анонимные классы. Далее он передает методу output(new class implements PersonWriter). Видимо в этом суть?

Comment: Автор имеет в виду что, то, как данные класса `Person` будут записаны в `writer`, решает сам `writer`, а не `Person`. Потому что иначе `Person` начинает знать слишком много о тех, кому нужны его данные. Судя по всему там где-то рядом поясняется паттерн `Посетитель`.